# Can't understand passage regarding surface tension

Tags: homework-and-exercises, water, density, surface-tension

I was reading about the [teapot effect](http://www.physics.org/featuredetail.asp?id=80) and couldn't figure out WHY the author came to the conclusion that he did, which is underlined in red in this image.

[image: passage]

Basically to summarise his experiment (or at least my take on it), first he immersed an [Erlenmeyer flask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlenmeyer_flask) in fresh water, upside down and poured a concentrated salt solution down the wide part of the flask (the bottom). Salt being heavier than water, he noticed that the salt solution ran down the slope of the flask in the water and sticks to the surface of the flask AGAINST gravity.(fig. 3)

Secondly, he did the same experiment except instead of **salt solution** being poured **down** onto a flask **immersed in water**, he inserted water below an upright flask immersed in salt solution. The water rose up the slope of the flask and stuck to the slope, again, against gravity. (fig.4)

His conclusion is that because of the results of these two experiments, the effect of liquid sticking to the slope of a surface CANNOT be caused by adhesion/[surface tension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension).

Why?

[Here's](http://www.chem.mtu.edu/~fmorriso/cm310/ReinerTeapotPhysToday1956.pdf) the full article. The text in question is on the second page.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument being made in the underlined text is simply that if surface tension were the mechanism, we'd expect the salt solution to cling to the glass in both setups (beaker upside down or right side up), or water to cling to the glass in both setups, since one of these liquids would have a lower interfacial energy with the glass. Since we see the NaCl solution clinging in one geometry and the water in the other, we conclude that it can't be surface tension or such interfacial  forces.

Neat paper, by the way. I wish there were more StackExchange questions like this one!